# Visual C++ : Where to add reference of a static library that I use?

Tags: visual-c++, linker, static-libraries

In Visual C++ 2010, how to tell the linker that a static library named `taglib` is located in `d:\blabla\tag.lib` ?

Thanks in advance.

PS : I have this error, probably because the linker doesn't know where to find `tag.lib` :
`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall agLib::String::~String(void)" (__imp_??1String@TagLib@@UAE@XZ)`. How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Specify your library folder here:

**Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories**

Ans, specify your lib file here:

**Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependancies**

Comment: thanks, but it hasn't solved the problem.
Even if I have done these 2 steps, I still get : 
`1>testou.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall TagLib::String::~String(void)" (__imp_??1String@TagLib@@UAE@XZ)
\testou.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals`

Comment: Are you building in debug or Release mode?
In debug mode, taglib will be appended with a 'd'.
**taglibd.lib**

Comment: I tried all these things, but it still doesn't work... (I'm in Release mode)